# rackspace cloud windows server vpn connections between servers using RRAS

Tags: windows, vpn

I have 2 soon to be 4 servers in rackspace cloud, they are windows 2008 64 bit r2 machines. I am trying to set up a private network with which I can VPN into. I have a proven working model of this currently but only if one of the servers uses the basic VPN connection on the current profile to connect to the other server (which is hosting RRAS for inbound vpn's), just like you'd connect with on your local computer. I wanted to set up a persistent demand-dial vpn connection between the servers. When I have one server use demand-dial to the other the connection fails after user account authorization, explaining that I need to check my network settings. Has anyone accomplished this before on rackspace cloud servers? Again, if I have the server use the basic vpn connection it connects fine and my private lan works, but demand-dial through RRAS does not and therefore I cannot get a persistent vpn connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set up a Rackspace Cloud Server and an AWS EC2 and both exhibit the same issue. I'm guessing Azure VM's do as well, which would explain why each company is coming out with their own VPN/WAN solution. As a workaround Hamachi works as intended, as any other 3rd party software likely would, such as a custom OpenVPN setup.